# Tracking userId across multiple Alexa skills

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

If I have created multiple Alexa skills, is there a userId that would remain the same across all the skills? Specifically, if user does an action in Skill 1, I'd like to be aware of it for Skills 2 and Skills 3... and essentially allow the skills to share the same DynamoDB table.

Ideally I wouldn't require the user to do any sort of login, but it would know it's the same user based on a unique identifier tied to their Amazon account.

Comment: Love the username!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  About a year ago Amazon made specific changes to prevent you from doing that.  You also can't identify a user who uninstalls your skill and then reinstalls it.  You always get a new random user id.

The same thing has been happening for mobile development: Google and Apple are blocking access to anything that would allow you to ID a physical device, or to ID a user of different app installs without doing some sort of account linking - so I doubt Amazon is going to relax about this.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this part of the documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/alexa-skills-kit-interface-reference#request-body-syntax), it should be possible by using the deviceId instead of userId:

> **device**
>   An object providing information about the device used to send the
>   request. The device object contains both deviceId and
>   supportedInterfaces properties. The deviceId property uniquely
>   identifies the device. [...]

You find it as:

```
deviceId = this.event.context.System.device.deviceId
```

It is the same value you need to use for requesting the device address with the new address api. Hence, I don't see why it shouldn't work for your needs also.